# MySQL's MD5 hash is incorrect

Tags: php, mysql, md5

PHP's md5("123123") gives me a correct value of 4297f44b13955235245b2497399d7a93, while mysql's

```
select md5("123123");
```

gives me '6e9abeea535938c496a261b3b39c0d79'.

Why would this happen ? does this have anything to do with mysql server incoding? I kinda lost it, help much appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: When I run `select md5("123123");` on MySQL 5.0.45 I get the same `4297f4...7a93` that you list for PHP.

Comment: I don't :) I get a different value from MySQL 5.1.44

Comment: i understand that you're very upset and angry with the universe right now :)

Comment: You can not imagine how much :) what a retard (me). can you delete your questions on this site?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`6e9abeea535938c496a261b3b39c0d79` is the value of `md5("132123")`,so I think you have a type mistake.

Comment: +1 You deserve a medal. Unless you just used http://md5crack.com/crackmd5.php , then much less impressive...

Comment: I get `04c63186ff836a823b1f7fa0f98f266a` as the md5 of "123123" (with the quotes as part of the string). How can I reproduce what you got?

Comment: `echo -n '"123123"' | md5sum`, `echo md5('"123123"');` (php), and `select md5('"123123"');` (mysql) all give me the value `04c63186ff836a823b1f7fa0f98f266a` ...

Answer (score 1):

I get the same value from mysql and php. Might have something to do with multi-byte characters?

---

```
mysql> select md5("123123");
+----------------------------------+
| md5("123123")                    |
+----------------------------------+
| 4297f44b13955235245b2497399d7a93 |
+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

- mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.41, for debian-linux-gnu (i486) using readline 6.1

---

```
php > echo md5("123123");
4297f44b13955235245b2497399d7a93
```

- PHP 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.5 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Sep 17 2010 13:41:55)

---