# MD5 Invalid in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

Another programmer worked on the checksum match of a forgot password script, I did the GUI stuff. I am having difficulty understanding the MD5 part of the query. With tests I see this is the issue. So how do I get the password changed successfully condition to hit? I pass in something like reset_pass.php?encrypt=cd00692c3bfe59267d5ecfac5310286c&action=reset (test data). I appreciate any help

I tested this down to see the md5 part is the problem (i get a success but password is not changed when I remove that).

```
...

function IsValidLink($encrypt)
{
    global $mysql_connect;  
    $ResultVal=false;

    $Query = "SELECT LNK.resetid FROM password_reset_requests LNK INNER JOIN users USI ON LNK.user_id=USI.id WHERE md5((90*3)+resetid)='".$encrypt."' AND DATE_ADD(dtsent , INTERVAL 4 HOUR) > now()";
    $result = mysql_query($Query);
    $RowCount = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if($RowCount >0)
        $ResultVal=true;    
    return $ResultVal;
}


if(isset($_GET['action']))
{          
    if($_GET['action']=="reset")
    {        
        $encrypt = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['encrypt']);
        $Query = sprintf("SELECT  resetid FROM password_reset_requests WHERE md5((90*3)+resetid)='%s'",$encrypt); 
        $result = mysql_query($Query,$mysql_connect);
        $RowCount = mysql_num_rows($result);        
               if($RowCount>0)
        {
            if(!IsValidLink($encrypt))
                $ErrMsg = "Reset password token has expired. please try again with new  <a href=\"".$ForgotPass_URL."\">Forget Password</a>";       
        }
        else
            $ErrMsg = "Invalid password token. please try again with new  <a href=\"".$ForgotPass_URL."\">Forget Password</a>";
    }
}
elseif(isset($_POST['action']))
{
    $encrypt    = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['encrypt']);   
    $NewPassword   = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['newpass']);   


if(IsValidLink($encrypt))
    {
        $Query = "SELECT LNK.resetid,LNK.user_id,USI.email,USI.name,USI.password FROM password_reset_requests LNK INNER JOIN users USI ON LNK.user_id=USI.id WHERE md5((90*3)+resetid)='".$encrypt."'";
        $result = mysql_query($Query,$mysql_connect);   
        if($objResult=mysql_fetch_object($result))
        {
            $UpdateSQL = "UPDATE users SET password='".md5($NewPassword)."' WHERE id='".$objResult->user_id."'";
            mysql_query($UpdateSQL,$mysql_connect);         
            $UpdateSQL="UPDATE password_reset_requests SET status='used',dtreset='".date('Y-m-d h:i:s')."',ip='".get_client_ip_env()."' WHERE resetid=".$objResult->resetid;            
            mysql_query($UpdateSQL,$mysql_connect);         

...
        }
        else
            $ErrMsg = "System Error. Try again later";  
    }
    else
    {
        $ErrMsg = "Reset password token has expired. please try again with new  <a href=\"".$ForgotPass_URL."\">Forget Password</a>";
    }

...
if($ErrMsg != "")
    echo $ErrMsg;


else if ($SucMsg !="")
    echo $SucMsg;

...


best way to get a success message with password changed
```

Comment: "With tests I see this is the issue."  _What_ issue?  What is happening?  What _should_ be happening?  What testing exactly did you do that led you to your conclusion?

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an unsuitable hashing algorithm](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) and need to [take better care](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) of your users' passwords.

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) that has been [removed](http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.php) from PHP. You should select a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL's MD5 hash is incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3783347/mysqls-md5-hash-is-incorrect)

Comment: @asiby That question was really just the result of a typo (and should actually be closed IMO), so I'm doubting it is related.

Comment: Ok. Sounds good.

Comment: Thanks everyone that is good insight, I was able to resolve the issue but I will make improvements as needed.

Comment: Please progress this page to some resolution.  All pages should eventuate to: 1. An educational and accepted answer 2. Question closure or 3. Question retraction/deletion.